# select subquery in postgresql get list

Tags: postgresql

I have Table:

```
stations (staion , phone , address)
```

AND

```
members (username , password , fullname , station)
```

I want to Station List , count username . So I wrote this query.

```
SELECT 
    stations.station as st,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(username) 
        FROM members 
        WHERE members.station = stations.station
    ) as co
FROM stations
GROUP BY stations.station
ORDER BY stations.station
```

It alerts (Error) :

```
'ERROR: subquery uses ungrouped column "stations.station" from outer query'
```

Please help me to get right data with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select stations.station as st,count(username) as co 
from member left join stations on member.station=stations.station 
group by stations.station 
order by stations.station;
```

Comment: I think you mean `left join`

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution is this:

```
SELECT 
stations.station as st,
(
    SELECT COUNT(username) 
    FROM members 
    WHERE members.station = ANY( array_agg( stations.station ) )
) as co
FROM stations
GROUP BY stations.station
ORDER BY stations.station
```

Comment: Yep, that worked for me! But according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/34627688/1676382 `=ANY` is less likely to use an index. However, when I tried a solution using `IN array_to_string(array_agg(stations.station), ',')` as a template, it still didn't didn't use an index for me :(

Answer (score 0):

simple answer without `join` is:

```
SELECT  stations.station, COUNT(username)
FROM stations, members
WHERE members.station = stations.station
GROUP BY stations.station
ORDER BY stations.station
```

Comment: Although you are not writing the `join` world you are still doing a `join`