# IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-in

What is the difference between `IN` and `ANY` operator in PostgreSQL?
The working mechanism of both seems to be the same. Can anyone explain this with an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [postgreSQL - in vs any](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263671/postgresql-in-vs-any)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between in and any operators in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699356/difference-between-in-and-any-operators-in-sql)

Answer (score 422):

(Strictly speaking, `IN` and `ANY` are Postgres "constructs" or "syntax elements", rather than "operators".)

***Logically***, [quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME):

> `IN` is equivalent to `= ANY`.

But there are two ***syntax variants*** of `IN` and two variants of `ANY`. Details:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause/31192557#31192557)

`IN` **taking a *set*** is equivalent to `= ANY` taking a *set*, as demonstrated here:

- [PostgreSQL - IN vs ANY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263671/postgresql-in-vs-any/30263897#30263897)

But the second variant of each is subtly different. The second variant of the `ANY` construct takes an **array** (must be an actual array type), while the second variant of `IN` takes a comma-separated **list of values**. This leads to different restrictions in passing values and *can* also lead to different query plans in special cases:

- [Index not used with `=any()` but used with `in`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125500/3684)
- [Pass multiple sets or arrays of values to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600567/pass-multiple-sets-or-arrays-of-values-to-a-function/34601242#34601242)
- [How to match elements in an array of composite type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69590314/how-to-match-elements-in-an-array-of-composite-type/69590967)

#### `ANY` is more versatile

The `ANY` construct is far more versatile, as it can be combined with various operators, not just `=`. Example:

```
SELECT 'foo' LIKE ANY('{FOO,bar,%oo%}');
```

For a big number of values, providing a *set* scales better for each:

- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/91247/3684)

Related:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

#### Inversion / opposite / exclusion

*"Find rows where `id` is in the given array":*

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = ANY (ARRAY[1, 2]);
```

Inversion: *"Find rows where `id` is **not** in the array":*

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id <> ALL (ARRAY[1, 2]);
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id <> ALL ('{1, 2}');  -- equivalent array literal
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE NOT (id = ANY ('{1, 2}'));
```

All three equivalent. The first with [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS), the other two with [array literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT). The type of the **untyped array literal** is derived from (known) element type to the left.
In other constellations (typed array value / you want a different type / ARRAY constructor for a non-default type) you may need to cast explicitly.

Rows with **`id IS NULL`** do not pass either of these expressions. To include `NULL` values additionally:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (id = ANY ('{1, 2}')) IS NOT TRUE;
```

Comment: It'd be nice to explicitly clarify that the results of the second variants will always be the same. I'm 99% sure that is in fact the case but the answer doesn't seem to state it. Meaning that `SELECT * from mytable where id in (1, 2, 3)` will always result in the same rows as `SELECT * from mytable where id = ANY('{1, 2, 3}')`, even if they potentially might have different query plans.

Comment: `ANY` **cannot** be combined with the `!=` operator. I don't think it's documented, but `select * from foo where id != ANY (ARRAY[1, 2])` is not the same as `select * from foo where id NOT IN (1, 2)`. On the other hand, `select * from foo where NOT (id = ANY (ARRAY[1, 2]))` works as expected.

Comment: @qris: `ANY` can be combined with the `!=` operator. But there is more to it. I added a chapter above. (Note that `<>` is the operator in standard SQL - though `!=` is accepted as well in Postgres.)

Comment: How does the last version that includes `NULL` values work? Would `WHERE id = ANY (ARRAY[1, 2]) OR id IS NULL;` work just as well?

Comment: @dvtan: `(id = ...) IS NOT TRUE` works because `id = ...` only evaluates to `TRUE` if there is an actual match. Outcomes `FALSE` or `NULL` pass our test. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23767625/939860. Your added expression tests for something else. This would be equivalent `WHERE id <> ALL (ARRAY[1, 2]) OR id IS NULL;`

Comment: It's said that index is not used with `=ANY('{1, 2, 3}')`, but I just tried to do both `WHERE key = ANY ('{1, 3, 5, ...49}')` as well as `WHERE key IN (1, 3, 5, ...49)` on a big table and the `EXPLAIN` output is absolutely the same and it uses index scan. Even more, it says `=ANY` in the explain output even for `IN`. I'm on PostgreSQL 12.4

Comment: @seriyPS: `It's said that index is not used ...`? I am not saying anything of the sort. If you mean "Index not used with =any() but used with in", that's just the title of a related question - linking to my related answer.

Comment: @erwin-brandstetter ah, ok, sorry. But I think others may be confused the same way as I did, so I'll leave the comment where it is.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I found out this commit patched. not sure how faster can it be to speed IN clause. https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=50e17ad28

Comment: @jian: That should help. But the release notes only mention a related improvement for `NOT IN`. I'll have to test. But not now ...

Answer (score 17):

There are two obvious points, as well as the points in the other answer:

- They are exactly equivalent when using sub queries:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE column IN(subquery);

  SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE column = ANY(subquery);
  ```

On the other hand:

- Only the `IN` operator allows a simple list:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE column IN(… , … , …);
  ```

Presuming they are exactly the same has caught me out several times when forgetting that `ANY` doesn’t work with lists.

Comment: For the "simple list" case, `WHERE id = ANY(array[1,2])` works.

Comment: or, using the example in this answer, `WHERE id = ANY(array(<subquery>))`

Answer (score 2):

`'in'` is syntaxis sugar, you can take a look to plan analyse and will see that 'in`'`  will be transform to `=ANY('...,...')::yourType[]`

Comment: I don't think this is true. I have a query that was taking 26 seconds to execute using an `IN` constraint (values from a subquery), but when I switched to an `= ANY(array(<subquery>))` the same query took a couple hundred milliseconds. The query plan definitely changed. PG 12.3

Comment: did the first attempt warm the cache maybe? run them both twice and see if the timing is different