# How to translate tag area into a PostgreSQL query?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pg-promise

I have a tag area where 0...N tags can be chosen. The tag area gives a comma separated list which will then be sent to the server for further processing.
For example, the tag csv-list can look like this:

> var taglist = ['important', 'less important']

I create an array out of it for it to be processed by LIKE ANY.

```
 var taglistArray = pgp.as.array(taglist);
```

There is a possible way with LIKE ANY but I could not get it to work.

```
 select * from $1:name WHERE importance LIKE ANY $4:list
 ...
 ['tablename', field2, field3, taglistArray]

error: syntax error at or near "'array[''important'',''less important'']'"
```

There seem to be several issues if the tag area is empty (hence the query should return everything and not nothing) and the ability to query a list instead of just one keyword.

How can a list of tags be translated into a SQL query in the best way using pg-promise?

Comment: Are you using `pgp.as.array` and then pass it in as a string? That would be wrong, the array is supposed to be passed in directly, if you are using filter `:list`. Also PostgreSQL syntax for `ANY` is with parentheses, i.e. `ANY($4:list)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per documentation examples](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#csv-filter), you use arrays directly, and not pre-convert them into strings:

```
var taglist = ['one', 'two'];
db.any('select * from $1:name WHERE importance LIKE ANY($2)', ['important', tagList])
```

And your code formats the array twice, and hence the double-escaping issue. It is only for `IN($2:list)` you would use the `:list` filter, but for `ANY` you need the array directly, i.e. `ANY($2)`, without any filter.

Also, the correct syntax for `ANY` is with parentheses - `ANY($2)`.

Comment: Thanks. I could get IN ($2:csv) working. 
However, I still struggle with LIKE ANY ($2:csv) when I just change IN into LIKE ANY. Do you know how that is supported?

Comment: @codebird456 I wouldn't speculate on the syntax of queries you generate. The right way to approach this - start using [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor), so you can see the actual queries being executed, and then they are easy to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that. But I have not found any info in the documentation you linked above about the combination of LIKE ANY ($2:csv). I could find just IN ($2:csv). 
Is that supported?

Comment: @codebird456 Yes, for `ANY` syntax do not use any filter. I have corrected the example ;) See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql

Comment: Hey thx. 
It works with ($2:raw) as well when passing pgp.as.array(xxx) as parameter to match LIKE ANY (array['term1,'term2','term3']) from postgres console

Comment: @codebird456 Yes, the effect in this case would be the same as simply not use any filter and pass in the array directly.