# sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type []int, a slice of in

Tags: postgresql, go

Have this:

```
somevars := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
rows, err = db.Query("SELECT c1,c2 FROM table"+tid+" WHERE c1 IN($1,$2,$3,$4);", somevars)
```

Got this:

sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type []int, a slice of int

Any way to make a slice of arguments work with lib/pq?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

pq.Array was  the answer:

```
somevars := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
rows, err = db.Query("SELECT c1,c2 FROM table"+tid+" WHERE c1 = any($1);", pq.Array(somevars))
```

Comment: You are replacing `IN` with `=`. Will they do the same thing in this case? Where is this documented?

Comment: @JohanWalles yep, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34627688/1168524

Comment: And here is the relevant part on official docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME

Answer (score 25):

An alternative solution is

```
somevars := []interface{}{1, 2, 3, 4}
rows, err = db.Query(
    "SELECT c1,c2 FROM table"+tid+" WHERE c1 IN($1,$2,$3,$4);",
    somevars...)
```

Here the `...` expands a slice to multiple arguments, similar to the python `*args`. It's documented [in the language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters).

The `db.Query` API supports this so called variadic parameter.

```
func (db *DB) Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (*Rows, error)
```

Here `interface{}` is known as the empty interface, and it can hold values of any type. See the [Go tour example here](https://tour.golang.org/methods/14). So one can use it like

`db.Query(stmt, var1, var2)`

where `var1` `var2` could be of different types.

In your case, you can also pass the slice elements explicitly

```
db.Query(stmt,
         somevars[0], somevars[1], somevars[2], somevars[3])
```

But it is rather verbose and requires extra work when the slice length changes.

Note that if instead of the `interface` slice `somevars`, we use `intvars := []int {1, 2, 3, 4}` and expand `intvars` in `db.Query()`, the compiler will complain on `intvars...`

> cannot use []int literal (type []int) as type []interface {} in assignment

Type conversion `intvars.([]interface{})` doesn't work either. This is documented in the [language spec FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface). And there is also a [dedicated wiki page for it](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice)

> It is disallowed by the language specification because the two types do not have the same representation in memory.

The intuitive picture of golang `interface` is an object with two fields, one field stores a type, and the other stores a pointer.

Comment: This is cool! But i need to convert the int slice to a type interface and that's a few extra lines of code.

Comment: There is no need for type conversion. `int` type (and all types) satisfies `interface{}` type. See [this example](https://play.golang.com/p/GX722BPxgaI).

Comment: Oh, so must be a buy or something in the linter. Will check it out, thanks!

Comment: I just tried and it indeed doesn't work. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 7):

A more generalizable solution is to use the `sqlx` library: https://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#inQueries

```golang
// assume db is an initialized database handle
somevars := []int{1,2,3,4}
query, args, err := sqlx.In("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (?)", somevars)
if err != nil {
  return err
}
query = db.Rebind(query)
result := db.Select(query, args...)
```

This solution will work with multiple database drivers and slices of unknown length.