# How to fix org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have an SQL query

```sql
select t.id as id, t.color as color from test_data t where t.id = ANY(?1) and t.color=?2
```

how can I pass an array of values to `ANY(?1)`

i.e

```java
em.createNamedQuery("Test.getTestData", Tuple.class)
   .setParameter(1, arrayOfIds<----___can_I_pass_an_array___?____)
   .setParameter(2, yellow)
   .unwrap(NativeQuery.class)
   .addScalar("id", LongType())
   .addScalar("color", new StringType())
```

I get an error

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side
      Position: 507
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible ways:

1. You can transform `= ANY(?1)` statement to the `in (?1)`. As it explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql), they have the same meaning. And then pass `List<Long>` instead of `Long[]`:

```java
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object[]> result = em.createNativeQuery(
   "select id, color from test_data where id in (:ids)")
   .setParameter("ids", ids)
   .getResultList();
```

2. You can add the following [dependency](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types):

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
   <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

if you use hibernate 5.4, 5.3 or 5.2 and then rewrite your query in the following way:

```java
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.LongArrayType;

Long[] ids = {1L, 3L};
List<Object[]> result = em.createNativeQuery(
   "select id, color from test_data where id = ANY(:ids)")
   .unwrap(org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class)
   .setParameter("ids", ids, LongArrayType.INSTANCE)
   .getResultList();
```

Instead of adding additional dependency you can also write your own hibernate [custom basic type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type), but it can be quite problematically without appropriate experience.

Comment: Thank you for your response, would it work if I used NamedNativeQuery and not a plain native query?

Comment: tried your second suggestion. Getting the same error

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side

Comment: Sorry, after reviewing the changes it seams to be working as expected. Thank you.

Comment: And it also  works with NamedNativeQuery (just tested)