# PostgreSQL array overlap with the ALL construct

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I want to achieve the same behavior as in next example:

```
select array[1, 3] && array[1] and array[1, 3] && array[2]
```

using the `ALL` construct like so:

```
select array[1, 3] && all(select array[array[1], array[2]])
```

By logic both queries should return `false`, but only the first does, while the second query returns `true`.

Can anybody explain this behavior and hint me how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing a *single multi-dimensional array*, pass a *set of 1-dimensional arrays* - or really any dimensions, as dimensions are just noise in this case. This works:

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,3] && ALL ((SELECT ARRAY[1] UNION ALL SELECT ARRAY[2]));  -- false
```

Which is more useful when applied to a table column:

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,3] && ALL ((SELECT array_column FROM some_tbl));
```

The `ALL` or `ANY` constructs either expect a *set* or an *array* to the right. Your example only works with a ***set***. I can see how one might conclude to pass a multi-dimensional array (an *array of arrays*). Unfortunately, that's not how it works. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.17):

> The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared **to each element of the array** [...],

Bold emphasis mine. Element. Not sub-array or array-slice. So the attempt:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY[1,3] && ALL (ARRAY[ARRAY[1], ARRAY[2]]);  -- error
-- identical, more explicit:
SELECT '{1,3}'::int[] && ALL ('{{1},{2}}'::int[]);  -- error
```

... results in this error message accordingly:

> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] && integer
> ```

You tried something in between:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY[1,3] && ALL(SELECT ARRAY[ARRAY[1], ARRAY[2]]);  -- true
-- identical, more explicit:
SELECT '{1,3}'::int[] && ALL (SELECT '{{1},{2}}'::int[]);  -- true
```

Effectively a *set* containing *single multi-dimensional array*. It boils down to:

```
SELECT '{1,3}'::int[] && '{{1},{2}}'::int[];  -- true
```

... which yields **`true`** like you observed because, again, "overlap" is tested on the level of *elements*, ignoring dimensions. Effectively the same as:

```
SELECT '{1,3}'::int[] && '{1,2}'::int[];  -- true
```

Or, to prove my point:

```
SELECT '{{{1}},{{3}}}'::int[] && '{{1},{2}}'::int[];  -- true
```

Related:

- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Erwin's answer here is a hack that you can use if you are able to represent inner arrays as strings:

```
select array[1, 3] && all(
  select string_to_array(unnest(array['1,2', '4,3']), ',')::int[]
)
```