# Greater than any element of array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, exists, any

I am facing this issue:

Is there a way in PostgreSQL to put aggregated timestamp data into an array (for example using `array_agg` function) and then **perform any match on some condition**?

I am doing something similar with `LIKE` on aggregated strings (using `string_agg(column,';')`). But how to perform something similar on timestamps?

So if result would be `'{10.10.2021,20.12.2021,1.1.1996}' as timestamp_array` and I would like to filter rows that have at least one array element that after some input?

For example, `... WHERE 31.12.2021 > timestamp_array ...` would not match the row above cause there is no array element after 31.12.2021.

But If I query `... WHERE 31.12.1996 > timestamp_array ...`, the row above would be matched (cause at least one element of the array is in given interval).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you would use standard date formats.  Then you can use:

```
where '2021-12-31' > any (timestamp_array)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c89849259e4f0261648ee9c106d26d93) is a db<>fiddle to illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to filter rows that has at least one array element that is after some input?

You **can** use the `ANY` construct as has been advised.

```
WHERE '1996-12-31'::timestamp < ANY ('{2021-10-10, 2021-12-20, 1996-01-01}'::timestamp[])
```

Has to be `<`, not `>`, obviously.
Your "timestamps" look a lot like dates - `timestamp` input accepts that, too.
But always use the [recommended ISO 8601 format](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE) (as demonstrated), else your input depends on setting of the current session.

See:

- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)

But chances are, there is **much more efficient** way. You speak of "aggregated timestamp data". Typically it's much more efficient to check *before* aggregating. Not least because that can use indexes, as opposed to your approach. Typically, `EXISTS` does the job. Something like:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM tbl t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id AND t1.timestamp_column > '1996-12-31'
GROUP  BY ...
```

Start a new question with details of your query to get a fitting solution.