# How to pass multiple condition in dynamic parameter in Dapper Query like we pass for IN operator

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, dapper, dynamicparameters

I want to pass multiple entity code while querying my PostgreSQL db. I am getting error with below code:
I want query to work like below:

```
        SELECT * FROM public.test WHERE entity_code IN('value1', 'value2');
```

Below is my code which works in case I am passing single value:

```
        string query = "SELECT * FROM public.test WHERE entity_code = @Entity_Code";

        Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dictionary.Add("@Entity_Code", "value1");

        var connection = _postgreSqlContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
        var results = connection.Query<Test>(query, new DynamicParameters(dictionary));
```

And below is the code which is not working in case multiple values added against same parameter:

```
    string query = "SELECT * FROM public.test WHERE entity_code IN @Entity_Code";

    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    dictionary.Add("@Entity_Code", new string[]{ "value1", "value2" });

    var connection = _postgreSqlContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
    var results = connection.Query<Test>(query, new DynamicParameters(dictionary));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres has a slightly different `IN`-syntax. You should use `ANY`:

```cs
string query = "SELECT * FROM public.test WHERE entity_code = ANY(@Entity_Code)";

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dictionary.Add("@Entity_Code", new string[]{ "value1", "value2" });

var connection = _postgreSqlContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
var results = connection.Query<Test>(query, new DynamicParameters(dictionary));
```

See the answer to this question: [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql)