# Return all data when grouping on a field

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate

I have the following 2 tables (there are more fields in the real tables):

```sql
create table publisher(id serial not null primary key,
name text not null);

create table product(id serial not null primary key,
name text not null,
publisherRef int not null references publisher(id));
```

Sample data:

```
insert into publisher (id,name) values (1,'pub1'),(2,'pub2'),(3,'pub3');
insert into product (name,publisherRef) values('p1',1),('p2',2),('p3',2),('p4',2),('p5',3),('p6',3);
```

And I would like the query to return:

```
name, numProducts
pub2, 3
pub3, 2
pub1, 1
```

A product is published by a publisher. Now I need a list of name, id of all publishers which have at least one product, ordered by the total number of products each publisher has.

I can get the id of the publishers ordered by number of products with:

```
select publisherRef AS id, count(*)
from product
order by count(*) desc;
```

But I also need the name of each publisher in the result. I thought I could use a subquery like:

```
select *
from publisher
where id in (
   select publisherRef
   from product
   order by count(*) desc)
```

But the order of rows in the subquery is lost in the outer `SELECT`.

Is there any way to do this with a single sql query?

Comment: If you can enter your sample data as well as the desired output I think you will get the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT pub.name, pro.num_products
FROM  (
   SELECT publisherref AS id, count(*) AS num_products
   FROM   product
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) pro
JOIN   publisher pub USING (id)
ORDER  BY 2 DESC;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c2f0e989c6bd49b69f77c296906c77cc)*

Or (since the title mentions "all data") return all columns of the publisher with `pub.*`. After products have been aggregated in the subquery, you are free to list anything in the outer `SELECT`.

This only lists publisher which

> have at least one product

And the result is ordered by

> the total number of products each publisher has

It's typically faster to aggregate the "n"-table *before* joining to the "1"-table. Then use an `[INNER] JOIN` (not a `LEFT JOIN`) to exclude publishers without products.

Note that the order of rows in an `IN` expression (or items in the given list - [there are two syntax variants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34627688/939860)) is insignificant.

The column alias in `publisherref AS id` is totally optional to use the simpler `USING` clause for identical column names in the following join condition.

Aside: avoid CaMeL-case names in Postgres. Use unquoted, legal, lowercase names exclusively to make your life easier.

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)