# Include NULL in WHERE Array?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with left joins that are creating NULL values. Let's say I'm interested in how many users have a basic plan or no plan at all (indicated by a NULL record in the left join)

```
SELECT u.id, s.plan_type 
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN subscriptions as s on s.user_id = u.id
WHERE s.plan_type IN (NULL, 'basic')
```

The above does not work as intended, likely because it doesn't recognize it as NULL. I'd have to write something like `WHERE s.plan_type IS NULL OR s.plan_type = 'basic'`

I was wondering if there was a short hand for that, or if you always have to use IS NULL to identify NULL values

Comment: In a few words, no, you have to do the `OR` what you said. Why is it that bad? Maybe the explanation is that `NULL` value cannot be compared with equal operator (e.g. `NULL = NULL` return false), and `IN` operator likely performs an equal comparison for each element

Comment: Not sure how it works in POSTGRES but one option would be to use a coalesce... WHERE coalesce(s.plan_type, '-1') IN ('-1', 'basic'). Essentially, replace NULL with -1, then you can check for -1.

Comment: @JaimeDrq  One reason it is bad is that an IN list can make more efficient use of indexes than an OR currently can.  (Maybe we will fix that some day)

Comment: I trust you @jjanes, but being honest I am not fully confident about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s.plan_type IN (NULL, 'basic')` is just shorthand for `(s.plan_type = NULL OR s.plan_type = 'basic')`.

`Anything = NULL` always returns `NULL`, not `true`. And only `true` qualifies in a `WHERE` clause. So rephrase:

```sql
SELECT u.id, s.plan_type 
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN subscriptions s ON s.user_id = u.id
WHERE (s.plan_type = 'basic' OR
       s.plan_type IS NULL);
```

To be precise, that's only correct if `subscriptions.plan_type` is defined `NOT NULL`. Failing that, the resulting `NULL` value could be just that, not a missing plan.

This alternative formulation does not share the same ambiguity for a resulting `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT u.id, s.plan_type
FROM   users u
JOIN   subscriptions s ON s.user_id = u.id
WHERE  s.plan_type = 'basic'
UNION ALL
SELECT u.id, NULL  -- always means missing
FROM   users u
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM subscriptions WHERE user_id = u.id);
```

And it may be faster, because Postgres (like most RDBMS) often doesn't perform well with `OR`'ed predicates. See about "ugly `OR`":

- [Why is an OR statement slower than UNION?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/293851/3684)

If referential integrity is guaranteed with a FK constraint from `subscriptions.user_id` to `users.id`, and `s.user_id` is defined `NOT NULL` you can omit the `users` table from the first `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT user_id AS id, plan_type
FROM   subscriptions
WHERE  plan_type = 'basic'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, NULL
FROM   users u
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM subscriptions WHERE user_id = u.id);
```

Might be fastest.

Aside: No *array* is involved here. You show the form of `IN` using a *list*. See:

- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)

Answer (score 3):

If your table isn't so huge, you could use `coalesce` to handle `null` before matching

```
select u.id, s.plan_type 
from users as u
left join subscriptions as s on s.user_id = u.id
where coalesce(s.plan_type,'basic') = 'basic';
```

Note that the use of function on the left side of the where clause will make the query [**unsargable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).