# Split String value from single to multiple values to fetch data using WHERE IN SQL clause

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have a request parameter which can accept single or comma separated values using `@RequestParam`.

Can you help me to break down or split the String of comma separated values so that it can be used when I pass those comma separated values in WHERE IN query clause?
This is what the url looks like:

`deviceName` parameter with single value: 
`getDevices?deviceName=Laptop`

`deviceName` parameter with comma separated values:
`getDevices?deviceName=Laptop,Smartphone,Camera,Television`

Currently my code like this:

```java
private List<Devices> processDisplay(List<String> deviceName) {
  Parameters parameters = new Parameters();
  parameters.setDeviceName(!deviceName.isEmpty() ? deviceName : null); \\deviceName is List<String> of type, EDITED: also added null checker
  List<Devices> devices = devicesRepository.getDevices(parameters);
};
```

How can I pass this comma separated values to SQL WHERE IN so it accepts the broke-down Strings into 4 records?

This is my `Repository` where my SQL is placed:

```java
public List<Devices> getDevices (Parameters parameters) {
  StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM devices d ");
  MapSqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();

  if (!parameters.getDeviceName().isEmpty())) {
    sql.append(" WHERE d.deviceName IN (:deviceName)");
    parameterSource.addValue("deviceName",parameters.getDeviceName().trim())
}
```

So that it will produce result like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM devices d 
WHERE d.deviceName IN ('Laptop','Smartphone','Camera','Television')
```

NOT like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM devices d 
WHERE d.deviceName IN ('Laptop, Smartphone,Camera,Television')
```

Help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can accept a `List<String>` of `devicesNames`, pass them to your `setDeviceNames()` method, which will also accept a `List<String>` and you will pass them here:

```
parameterSource.addValue("deviceName", parameters.getDeviceNames());
```

Comment: Thank you! But why do I get null as a response when my `devicesName` parameter has no value being passed? Considering that I created a condition where the sql `WHERE IN` will only append if the `devicesName` has a value, else, will return all devices. I did it like this `if (!parameters.getdevicesName().isEmpty()) {
sql.append(" WHERE d.deviceName IN (:deviceName)");
parameterSource.addValue("deviceName", parameters.getDeviceName());
}`

Comment: Probably because an empty list is passed which passes your if-condition check, which you can also debug and verify. So, you can add a !list.isEmpty() check too, before adding the condition to the sql query.

Comment: I see that you edited your comment. Can you add a non-null check in addition to the current !isEmpty() check? Also, can you update your post with you most recent code?

Comment: I added a null checker and updated my post with recent code as well, but I still encounter this `API Error.: null`

Comment: change this:   parameters.setDeviceName(!deviceName.isEmpty() ? deviceName : null); to:
if (deviceName != null && !deviceName.isEmpty()) {set....}
This way you are guaranteeing that you are only setting a value to your object if it is non-null and valid

Comment: But if my `deviceName` is null or empty, it should still be passed in my `Repository` class which contains the SQL but will not pass through the `sql.append(" WHERE d.deviceName IN (:deviceName)");` so that only the `SELECT * FROM devices d ` will be processed if my `deviceName` is null or empty.

Comment: Correct, by doing what I suggested you above, along with using the same if-condition in your Repository class, only this statement will be executed in null or empty-cases: SELECT * FROM devices d

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
sql.append(" WHERE d.deviceName IN (:deviceName)")
```

with

```
sql.append(" WHERE d.deviceName = any(string_to_array(:deviceName, ','))")
```

Your comma-separated parameter will be split into an array. `IN (<list>)` and `= any(<array>)` are equivalent in this case.
The result will be

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM devices d 
WHERE 
  d.deviceName = any(string_to_array('Laptop,Smartphone,Camera,Television', ','))
```

Using `any` unleashes a lot of power. You may have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql) if interested.