# SELECT WHERE column values are in array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, where-clause

Suppose I have a table called 'myTable':

```
columnA|    columnB|    columnC
   1   |     Yellow|     Apple
   3   |     Red   |     Grape
   8   |     Blue  |     Banana
   6   |     Green |     Orange
```

The above table is a simplification of an actual table for demo purposes. Imagine actual table is 100K + rows. Now, I want to select only the rows where columnB is in a list/array: ex - ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green']. I am not sure the right syntax to use here.

```
 SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE columnB IN Array['Red', 'Blue', 'Green']
```

Whats the proper syntax to achieve this?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE columnB IN ('Red', 'Blue', 'Green')` see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WHERE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the example, I believe its for MS SQL

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, e.JobTitle  
FROM Person.Person AS p  
    JOIN HumanResources.Employee AS e  
    ON p.BusinessEntityID = e.BusinessEntityID  
WHERE e.JobTitle IN ('Design Engineer', 'Tool Designer', 'Marketing Assistant');
```

Or in simple words (pay attention to text if its in lower, upper or proper base).

```
SELECT * FROM design WHERE Color IN ('Red', 'Green', 'Blue');
```

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, you can use an array, too, with `= ANY ()`:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE columnB = ANY (ARRAY['Red', 'Blue', 'Green']);
```

Or with a literal array constant as input:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE columnB = ANY ('{Red, Blue, Green}'::text[]);
```

It's equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE columnB IN ('Red', 'Blue', 'Green');
```

Related:

- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)