# How do I pass an array to where clause in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to delete from a table using where clause while passing it an array.

```sql
DELETE FROM Btemp
WHERE col2 =
    (SELECT ARRAY((SELECT col2 FROM Atemp INTERSECT SELECT col2 FROM Btemp)));
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = character varying[]
LINE 2: WHERE col2 =
                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
```

And if do it without array, like below

```sql
DELETE FROM Btemp
WHERE col2 =
    (SELECT col2 FROM Atemp INTERSECT SELECT col2 FROM Btemp);
```

I get error:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

What should I do?

Comment: Tip: WRITING IN ALL CAPITALS is often used to represent SHOUTING, so may be considered rude.

Comment: `where col2 in (select col2 from ...)`

Comment: sorry if you found it rude. im new to this .

Comment: Data types are essential. You cannot compare a scalar (individual) to a collection (array/ population). (you *could* try to find out if it is *part* of that collection)

Comment: Thank You. the IN keyword solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Btemp
WHERE col2 =
    ANY(SELECT col2 FROM Atemp INTERSECT SELECT col2 FROM Btemp);
```

further reference: [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql)