# Is there any SQL function or way to do this?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, where-clause

Is there any way we can do this in SQL?

Les say I have table `Tablename_1` as below:

| id | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | data1 |
| 2 | data2 |
| 3 | data3 |
| 4 | data4 |
| 5 | data5 |

I want to check if the data I have in my where clause is present in the table or not
for example, where clause is as:

```
where id in (1,3,5,7);
```

Then I wish to output as below:

| id | data_result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | YES |
| 3 | YES |
| 5 | YES |
| 7 | NO |

Comment: Best to create a temp table to hold the values and then do a LEFT JOIN from that temp table to your `Tablename_1`. There are other ways to pull this off by hardcoding in a CTE depending on what RDBMS you are using. If you can tag the RDBMS we can help further (postgres, sql server, mysql, oracle, etc).

Comment: its for MySQL and Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

One option is to provide your IDs as a [table-valued constructor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html) (`VALUES()` clause) instead of a WHERE clause. Then you can LEFT JOIN from this new "table" to create your result.

This is the MySql version (Postgresql needs to remove the `row` keywords):

```
select a.n, case when t1.id IS NULL then 'N' else 'Y' end as data_result
from (values row(1), row(3),row(5),row(7)) as a(n)
left join tablename_1 t1 on a.n = t1.id
```

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=028e5a984e5ed2969247e025bc8776be

You can also do this in a CTE via UNION:

```
WITH base as (
    SELECT 1 as n UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 7
)
SELECT base.n, case when t1.id IS NULL then 'N' else 'Y' end as data_result
FROM base
LEFT JOIN tablename_1 t1 on base.n = t1.id
```

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef2a88f6f89bf4101d7d651b4440ac28

This works the same in both databases, but as you can see means building a up lot more code per value in your list.

A final option is creating a [dynamic numbers table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained-part-1/). Then you can again LEFT JOIN these tables together to find out the Yes/No result for all possible values in the dynamic table and then still put your desired values in a WHERE clause to only show those results. The trick here is it requires you to have some idea of the possible scope for your values up front, and can make things a little slower if your guess is too far off.

Any of these could also be written to use an `EXISTS()` clause, which can often perform better. I just find the `JOIN` easier to write and reason about.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I don't want to create any temp table. Will this process create any temp table?

Comment: Not exactly. Both of these build up the set within the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use exists with the values approach from Joel

Something like

```
select v.*,
case when exists(select 1 from Tablename_1 as t where t.id=v.id) then 
    'Yes' 
else    
    'No' 
end 
from (values (1),(3),(5),(7)) as v(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANY.

```
select Tablename_1.id, 
       case 
            when Tablename_1.id = ANY (ARRAY[1, 3,5,7]) 
            then 'YES' 
            else 'NO' end  
           as data_result 
from Tablename_1;
```

further reading: [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql)

Comment: You don't really need the CASE expression: `id = any (...)` will return a boolean value directly