# Using column from SELECT INTO in WHERE ANY in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a `SELECT INTO` query like the following in a procedure :

```
declare

employee_data record;
item record

begin

select * into employee_data from employees where emp_id=10;
```

Now I am using a column from the `employee_data` variable in another query:

```
FOR item in 
  SELECT CONCAT(E.first_name,' ',E.last_name) AS employee_name, 
  E.email AS employee_email
  INTO notify_users_data
  FROM employee_info E
  WHERE E.emp_id = ANY(ARRAY employee_data.notify_users)
LOOP
```

Here, the `notify_users` column in `employee` table is of type `jsonb` and it is an array like `["2001", "3457"]`

When I try to save this query, it is showing a syntax error

`error:syntax error at or near employee_data: WHERE E.emp_id = ANY(ARRAY employee_data`

How can I use the result in WHERE ANY ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  employee_data record;
  item record;
  -- notify_users_data record;  -- ?
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO employee_data FROM employees WHERE emp_id = 10;

  FOR item IN
    SELECT concat_ws(' ', e.first_name, e.last_name) AS employee_name  -- makes more sense
         , e.email AS employee_email
    -- INTO   notify_users_data  -- nonsense
    FROM   employee_info e
--  WHERE  e.emp_id = ANY(employee_data.notify_users)  -- ①
    WHERE  employee_data.notify_users ? e.emp_id       -- ②
  LOOP
     RAISE NOTICE '%', item;
  END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

The additional keyword `ARRAY` made no sense.

① If `notify_users` is a Postgres array type, use it as is. See:

- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)

② If `notify_users` is type `jsonb` of the form `["2000", "3000"]`, and `emp_id` is a string type (not a numeric type!), you can use the [**`?`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) as demonstrated.

A [`FOR` loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) works with an implicit cursor. Each row is assigned to `item` - as declared at the top. The additional `INTO notify_users_data` made no sense.

Some other minor edits.

Can be simplified further:

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  item record;
BEGIN
  FOR item IN
    SELECT concat_ws(' ', i.first_name, i.last_name) AS employee_name, i.email AS employee_email
    FROM   employee_data d
    JOIN   employee_info i ON d.notify_users ? i.emp_id
  LOOP
     RAISE NOTICE '%', item;
  END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

Comment: Thanks. When I used notify_user as it is without `ARRAY`, I am getting this error `ANY/ALL (array) requires array on the right side`. This column is of type `jsonb` and hence a JSON array like ["2000", "3000"]. That's why I am trying to convert it into an array

Comment: @HappyCoder: I added a solution for `jsonb`. Please remember to add essential information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is an array then you can use the `UNNEST` function to convert array elements to the selected table data.
Example:

```
WHERE E.emp_id in (select t1.pval from unnest(employee_data.notify_users) t1(pval))
```

If your variable in this format `["2001", "3457"]` then you can firstly use `jsonb_array_elements_text` function and after then `UNNEST` function.
Example:

```
WHERE E.emp_id in (select jsonb_array_elements_text('["2001", "3457"]'::jsonb)::int4)
```