# Get distinct members for an array of group IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many, sql-in

I have 3 tables:

1. Scorecard
2. Group
3. Scorecard_Group (Joint table)

I am trying to write a query that fulfills the following purpose:

1. Get the list of distinct scorecard ids WHERE Scorecard_Group.groupId IN (Pass array of groupIds)
2. Get all Scorecard."name" where Scorecard."id" IN (Array of scorecardIds that we just queries)

I am able to achieve this using 2 queries but I would like for an optimal solution. Here is my 2 queries solution:

```
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT sg."scorecardId") as "ids"
FROM scorecard_group sg
WHERE sg."groupId" IN (${groupIds.concat()})


SELECT sc."id", sc."name"
FROM "scorecard" sc
WHERE sc."id" IN (${scIds[0].ids.concat()})
```

I tried to achieve the same result in 1 query but I am getting:

> ```
> column "scIds" does not exist
> ```

```
SELECT sc."name", sc."id",
       ( 
   SELECT DISTINCT sg."scorecardId"
   FROM scorecard_group sg
   WHERE sg."groupId" IN (${groupIds.concat()})
       ) as "scIds"
FROM "scorecard" sc
WHERE sc."id" IN ("scIds")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a proper many-to-many implementation like:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Seems like you twisted / over-complicated your objective as well as your query.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT s.id, s.name
FROM   scorecard_group sg
JOIN   scorecard       s  ON s.id = sg.scorecard_id
WHERE  sg.group_id = ANY ('{1,2,3}')  -- your array of group_id's here!
ORDER  BY 1, 2;  -- optional order
```

This retrieves the full, distinct ***set*** of scorecards (id, name) that are member in the given groups (array of group_id's).

Or, the same a bit faster for many duplicate memberships:

```sql
SELECT s.scorecard_id, s.name
FROM   scoeguard s
JOIN  (
   SELECT DISTINCT sg.scorecard_id
   FROM   scorecard_group sg
   WHERE  sg.group_id = ANY ('{1,2,3}')  -- your array of group_id's here!
   ) sg ON sg.scorecard_id = s.id
ORDER  BY 1, 2;  -- optional order
```

Using legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers like you should, too. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

To use `IN`, you'd have to provide a ***set*** or ***list***.
Use `= ANY` for an ***array***. See:

- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)

Comment: Indeed I have over complicated and knew that it could be done in a more efficient manner given that I have made the many to many relationship. Much appreciated for the answer and the insight regarding IN and ANY.

Comment: Mind if I ask out of curiosity what was wrong in my query in case I needed to use the values of the subquery in another use case later.

Comment: @charleslenx: You cannot reference an output column generated in the `SELECT` list (`"scIds"`) from a `WHERE` clause, which is applied *before* computing the `SELECT` list. Consider the *"Sequence of events in a SELECT query"* here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242764/939860