# how to query with List<String> in IN OPERATOR - flutter/dart with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch records from PostgreSQL DB by applying filters (where condition with IN operator). However **Something wrong while converting string to iterable element**. suggestions will be appreciated.

```
List<dynamic> detailedPositions = [];
  Future<List<dynamic>> fetchDetailedPositions(String custID) async {
    try {
      print(custID);               //output: ABC123, LP8338
      print(custID.runtimeType);   //output: string 
      await connection!.open();
      await connection!.transaction((fetchDataConn) async {
        _fetchMasterPositionData = await fetchDataConn.query(
          "select cust_id, array_agg((cust_id, cust_name, quantity, item_nme, average_price)) from orders
          where cust_id in (select cust_id from string_to_array(@cust_id,',')) and status='OPEN'"
          substitutionValues: {'cust_id': custID, 'status': status},
          timeoutInSeconds: 30,);
      });
    } catch (exc) {
      print('Exception in fetchDetailedPositions');
      print(exc.toString());
      detailedPositions = [];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dbfiddle.uk demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/N9u_RU1k)
The following code is wrong:

```
where cust_id in (select cust_id from string_to_array(@cust_id,','))
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTION-STRING-TO-ARRAY  string_to_array return text array.

You cannot use

```
select text 'hello'  in '{"hello","world"}'::text[];
```

correct *IN* construct:

```
select text 'hello' in ( text 'hello','world');
```

You can also use ANY:

```
select text 'hello'  = any( '{"hello","world"}'::text[]);
```

*IN vs ANY*: [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql)

So your query will be like

```
SELECT
    cust_id,
    ARRAY_AGG((cust_id, cust_name, quantity, item_nme, average_price))
FROM orders
WHERE cust_id IN (SELECT cust_id FROM string_to_array('ABC123, LP8338', ',')) AND status = 'OPEN'
GROUP BY
    1;
```

However, this query return data types are something like:

```
  Column   |   Type
-----------+----------
 cust_id   | text
 array_agg | record[]
(2 rows)
```

record[] usage most of time will have some problem, better use json.
So  the following will do.

```
SELECT
    cust_id,
    json_agg((
        SELECT
            x
        FROM (SELECT cust_id, cust_name, quantity, item_nme, average_price) AS x)) AS item
FROM orders
WHERE cust_id IN (SELECT cust_id FROM string_to_array('ABC123, LP8338', ',')) AND status = 'OPEN'
GROUP BY
    1;
```

json_agg usage: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/select-columns-inside-json-agg

Answer (score 0):

This helped me

```
var valuesString1 = custID.map((word) => word.trim()).toList();
String valuesString = valuesString1.map((e) => "'$e'").join(',');

_fetchMasterPositionData = await fetchDataConn.query(
  "SELECT cust_id, cust_name, net_quantity, net_stock_symbol, net_average_price, net_product_type, net_m2m, net_last_price, false AS isSelected FROM positions WHERE cust_id IN ($valuesString) AND net_status = 'OPEN'",
);
```