# postgresql query -> WHERE identifierin an array of strings

Tags: typescript, postgresql

I am trying to make a query to a postgis/postgresql server which gets items like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM "ContextBuilding"
WHERE "id" = ANY('UM3cxUnOtOmMsD79zcRWb','ulDME73WOGaChCbLH63iY','UoX9NoJIzANpXBvrjXQVx'::text[]) AND
coords &&
ST_MakeEnvelope(13.445188084976532, 52.52807719874824, 13.44677407320652, 52.529087036036735, 4326)
```

The problem is the the line `WHERE "id" ...`.
How can I check against an array of strings?

Ultimately, I want to generate this query from a typescript code like so:

```
const query = `
  SELECT *
  FROM ContextBuilding
  WHERE "id" = ANY(${tenantBuildingIDs}::text[]) AND
  coords &&
  ST_MakeEnvelope(${bounds[0]}, ${bounds[1]}, ${bounds[2]}, ${bounds[3]}, 4326)
  `
```

But this fails for the same reason.

A sample Output from:

```
SELECT volume, id, uid, coords FROM "ContextBuilding"
```

looks like this:

[image: sample output]

Comment: Please share sample data an expected result.

Comment: i have added the output from: SELECT volume, id, uid, coords FROM "ContextBuilding"
to the question

Comment: A list of values is not an array. Perhaps change `ANY(...)` to `ANY(ARRAY[...])`. When posting a question regarding an exception, please include the actual error that is being reported.

Comment: holy!! that easy ;) this works and solves my question: 
 SELECT * FROM "ContextBuilding"
WHERE "id" = ANY(ARRAY['UM3cxUnOtOmMsD79zcRWb','ulDME73WOGaChCbLH63iY','UoX9NoJIzANpXBvrjXQVx'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `IN` with a **list**:

```
WHERE  id  IN ('UM3cxUnOtOmMsD79zcRWb','ulDME73WOGaChCbLH63iY','UoX9NoJIzANpXBvrjXQVx'::text[])
```

Or `= ANY ()` with an **array**:

```
WHERE  id = ANY('{UM3cxUnOtOmMsD79zcRWb,ulDME73WOGaChCbLH63iY,UoX9NoJIzANpXBvrjXQVx}'::text[]))
```

Either would also accept a **set** from subquery. See:

- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)