# This query is slow because I think I'm using a lot of id values in the ANY() clause, isn't it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance, database-indexes

I have this table in Postgres:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.products 
(
    id character varying NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
);
```

As `id` I'm using ULID (note the column type in Postgres is `varchar` with no fixed length).

I'm ready to change the column type if needed.

```sql
SELECT "products".* 
FROM "products" 
WHERE "id" = ANY('{01HQDMCF0S7QWQYBP2FW9HK8DS,01HQDMCF11PB3N1Q9TXME6KW1B,01HQDMCF0YFZBAV5K4ZQ3495FR,01HQDMCF0S7QWQYBP2FW9HK8DS,01HQDMCF0WJ53MH0WKNR65CBX1,01HQDMCF0ZV7TYZWRR6RN5V4QT,01HQDMCF0YRF7CB3DSC6DSAY54,01HQDMCF0YFZBAV5K4ZQ3495FR,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF0S7QWQYBP2FW9HK8DS,01HQDMCF0S7QWQYBP2FW9HK8DS,01HQDMCF0YCJ8EFYCBKHWN4VQN,01HQDMCF0Z46AY42FC8FR953D8,01HQDMCF0S7QWQYBP2FW9HK8DS,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF0ZBQ3A70GE8K41RW1V,01HQDMCF0WNYW4ZH5G0M8MDAQA,01HQDMCF0ZM8B6BJJK38PH7M2F,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF0WT7K7W5GBFF3HVXHE,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF0W24YQHH4EKN91S0JY,01HQDMCF0WT7K7W5GBFF3HVXHE,01HQDMCF0ZM8B6BJJK38PH7M2F,01HQDMCF0YEQR7NJJJW88XNTW9,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF0YRF7CB3DSC6DSAY54,01HQDMCF0WBY0YT5MR53KG9HS8,01HQDMCF0WBY0YT5MR53KG9HS8,01HQDMCF106M1667NNPTDBKQDB,01HQDMCF0S7QWQYBP2FW9HK8DS,01HQDMCF0YFZBAV5K4ZQ3495FR,01HQDMCF0YFZBAV5K4ZQ3495FR,01HQDMCF0ZMPTQ0GHG0V87W0J4,01HQDMCF0ZM8B6BJJK38PH7M2F,01HQDMCF0ZM8B6BJJK38PH7M2F,01HQDMCF0WBY0YT5MR53KG9HS8,01HQDMCF0WHNJ0P9BGVEFJE2JG,01HQDMCF109V71KW4MTFWVRTFR,and a lot more ~ 20k of them}') 
LIMIT 37520 OFFSET 0
```

which is slow.

**IMPORTANT**

I'm using a lot (~ 20k) `id` values in the `ANY()` clause. And I think this is the problem.

If I use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` it says:

```
Limit  (cost=85.51..90.82 rows=154 width=172) (actual time=1.765..1.799 rows=138 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on products  (cost=85.51..90.82 rows=154 width=172) (actual time=1.764..1.791 rows=138 loops=1)
        Filter: ((id)::text = ANY ('{01HQDMCF0S7QWQYBP2FW9HK8DS,01HQDMCF11PB3N1Q9TXME6KW1B,01HQDMCF0YFZBAV5K4ZQ3495FR,01HQDMCF0S7QWQYBP2FW9HK8DS,01HQDMCF0WJ53MH0WKNR65CBX1,01HQDMCF0ZV7TYZWRR6RN5V4QT,01HQDMCF0YRF7CB3DSC6DSAY54,01HQDMCF0YFZBAV5K4ZQ3495FR,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF0S7QWQYBP2FW9HK8DS,01HQDMCF0S7QWQYBP2FW9HK8DS,01HQDMCF0YCJ8EFYCBKHWN4VQN,01HQDMCF0Z46AY42FC8FR953D8,01HQDMCF0S7QWQYBP2FW9HK8DS,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF0ZBQ3A70GE8K41RW1V,01HQDMCF0WNYW4ZH5G0M8MDAQA,01HQDMCF0ZM8B6BJJK38PH7M2F,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF0WT7K7W5GBFF3HVXHE,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF0W24YQHH4EKN91S0JY,01HQDMCF0WT7K7W5GBFF3HVXHE,01HQDMCF0ZM8B6BJJK38PH7M2F,01HQDMCF0YEQR7NJJJW88XNTW9,01HQDMCF11Z9VKEQXNZKEWXRDN,01HQDMCF0YRF7CB3DSC6DSAY54,01HQDMCF0WBY0YT5MR53KG9HS8,01HQDMCF0WBY0YT5MR53KG9HS8,01HQDMCF106M1667NNPTDBKQDB,01HQDMCF0S7QWQYBP2FW9HK8DS,01HQDMCF0YFZBAV5K4ZQ3495FR,01HQDMCF0YFZBAV5K4ZQ3495FR,01HQDMCF0ZMPTQ0GHG0V87W0J4,01HQDMCF0ZM8B6BJJK38PH7M2F,01HQDMCF0ZM8B6BJJK38PH7M2F,01HQDMCF0WBY0YT5MR53KG9HS8,01HQDMCF0WHNJ0P9BGVEFJE2JG,01HQDMCF109V71KW4MTFWVRTFR,and a lot more ~ 20k of them}'::text[]))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 16
Planning Time: 9.769 ms
Execution Time: 1.878 ms
```

I tried:

```
CREATE INDEX product_id_idx ON products(id);
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX product_id_idx ON products USING HASH(id);
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX product_id_pattern_idx ON products USING btree (id text_pattern_ops);
```

But they don't fix the extreme slowness.

What index can I create to improve the query?

Comment: 1) If you are using `UUID` why are you not using the [UUID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) type? 2) Where are you getting the `id`s in the ANY()?

Comment: `ANY` presumably is logically similar to `OR`, and therefore would not use your indices.

Comment: 1) Because I don't know what benefit I would have and I don't know how to do, since if I try Postgres throw with `invalid input syntax for type uuid: "\x01HQDMCF0S7QWQYBP2FW9HK8DS`. 2) From an external file.

Comment: Also I am not sure how comparing 20k values to 138 rows in `1.878 ms` is slow?

Comment: 1) I misread and saw `UUID` when it is really `ULID`. Not familiar with `ULID`, but I'm sure that the Postgres `UUID` type will not work with them. I led you astray. 2) This `\x01HQDMCF0S7QWQYBP2FW9HK8DS` is some sort of encoding. How are the values being generated?

Comment: They are valid ULIDs generated not by me, but they are store in database of course.

Comment: HOW do you generate the contents of that ANY()?  This may have a bearing on how to solve your issue. Also, please look at this answer that compares IN() to ANY()  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql

 **also** how fast is it if you only have one value inside the ANY? or 10 values? 40 values? i.e. is there a point at which it becomes too slow?

Comment: 2ms is extremely slow?

Comment: What kind of performance do you expect? 2 milliseconds is not extremely slow

Comment: @jjanes If you scroll to the right, the 2ms plan is for the example query that used a list of 43 tokens, last one saying *and a lot more ~ 20k of them*. I'm guessing the one that did actually use 20k tokens took a bit more than 2ms.

Comment: @Zegarek I thought he truncated it for presentation, for purposes of not getting rejected by stack overflow, rather than for purposes of actually doing the execution plan. It is going to be hard can't see what the problem really is.  I can fill in 20000 strings of garbage for myself, but can't fill in missing timings.

Comment: @AdrianMaxwell with hundreds of values it is fast (a few ms), with thousands it gets much worse.

Comment: @jjanes, @Frank Heikens, where do you see `2ms`? I wrote: `Planning Time: 9.769 ms
Execution Time: 1.878 ms`.

Comment: @FredHors 1.878ms is a bit under 2ms. That’s a decimal point, not a thousand separator

Comment: On my PC the data comes after 1,9 seconds...

Comment: @FredHors The execution plan you showed us was fast.  Maybe you misread the stopwatch feature on your PC, maybe it was slow one time and fast the rest due to cache hotness issues, maybe you have a network latency problem between your PC and the server, maybe your PC obtained the data very quickly but then was very slow displaying it.

Comment: Ok. Sorry I thought 1.878 ms was 1.9 seconds. Because 1,9 seconds is the tiem I wait in the Postgres client when I launch the query without `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. So now I need to understand why the EXPLAIN ANALYZE is fast and the actual query is slow.

Comment: @FredHors see my [update](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78066418/4) - I failed to reproduce it after all. **1)** Is `=any()` the only condition in `where`? Do you censor the code or the plan in any way before posting? **2)** How exactly do you pass/generate/retrieve the array you give to `any()`? **3)** What client are you running these tests in? **4)** Do they hit a remote or a local db? **5)** Mentioning the 1.9s (not ms) you're saying it takes to finish, how do you get/measure the 1.9 second score?

Comment: "with hundreds" = fast, but "with thousands" = slow. I suggest (again) that you tell use how you generate the any() parameter - in that process I suggest a solution can be found. (e.g. temp table) - but knowing zero about how you create the parameter list severely limits the available options.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't go all the way up to 20k, but [`=ANY(ARRAY[])`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-ANY-SOME) does seem reluctant to use the indexes you made available, sequentially scanning a freshly `vacuum analyze`'d table with 200k rows. [Demo1:](https://dbfiddle.uk/gncWOPH0)

```sql
SELECT "products".* 
FROM "products" 
WHERE "id" = ANY(ARRAY[(random())::text,(random())::text,...around 400 of these ...(random())::text]) 
LIMIT 37520 OFFSET 0
```

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=0.00..748971.00 rows=426 width=59) (actual time=17519.944..17519.952 rows=0 loops=1)
  Output: id, created_at, name
  ->  Seq Scan on public.products  (cost=0.00..748971.00 rows=426 width=59) (actual time=14365.282..14365.286 rows=0 loops=1)
        Output: id, created_at, name
        Filter: (products.id = ANY (ARRAY[(random())::text,(random())::text,...around 400 of these ...(random())::text]))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 200000
Planning Time: 1.387 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 4
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 10.140 ms, Inlining 81.166 ms, Optimization 1052.392 ms, Emission 2021.084 ms, Total 3164.782 ms
Execution Time: 17710.315 ms
```

It's resolved if you trade that for equivalent [`IN (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[]))`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN). [Demo2:](https://dbfiddle.uk/pVGBRjOJ)

```sql
SELECT "products".* 
FROM "products" 
WHERE "id" IN (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[(random())::text,(random())::text,...around 400 of these ...(random())::text])) 
LIMIT 37520 OFFSET 0
```

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=6.41..1481.91 rows=426 width=59) (actual time=0.816..0.817 rows=0 loops=1)
  Output: products.id, products.created_at, products.name
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=6.41..1481.91 rows=426 width=59) (actual time=0.815..0.816 rows=0 loops=1)
        Output: products.id, products.created_at, products.name
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=6.41..8.41 rows=200 width=32) (actual time=0.198..0.251 rows=426 loops=1)
              Output: (unnest(ARRAY[(random())::text, ...400 of these..., (random())::text]))
              Group Key: unnest(ARRAY[(random())::text, ...400 of these..., (random())::text])
              Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 77kB
              ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.34 rows=426 width=32) (actual time=0.069..0.102 rows=426 loops=1)
                    Output: unnest(ARRAY[(random())::text, ...400 of these..., (random())::text])
                    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using product_id_idx2 on public.products  (cost=0.00..7.36 rows=1 width=59) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=426)
              Output: products.id, products.created_at, products.name
              Index Cond: (products.id = (unnest(ARRAY[(random())::text, ...400 of these..., (random())::text])))
Planning Time: 1.050 ms
Execution Time: 0.989 ms
```

Now using the index, it goes down from `17s` to `1ms`.

---

[Turntables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78064326/this-query-is-slow-because-i-think-im-using-a-lot-of-id-values-in-the-any-cla/78066418?noredirect=1#comment137628816_78066418): I'll leave the above in for context but unless you're generating your ids similarly, it shouldn't apply. There still *might* be some advantage of `IN` over `ANY`, but your index *should* already work as it is. [`ANY`: demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/3Lcj_KfJ)

```sql
explain analyze verbose
WITH cte AS MATERIALIZED
  (select array_agg(r) as search_for_this
   from (select left(random()::text,9) as r
         from generate_series(1,2e4))_)
SELECT "products".* 
FROM "products", cte
WHERE "id" = ANY(search_for_this)
LIMIT 37520 OFFSET 0;
```

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=62.59..100.77 rows=10 width=50) (actual time=26.927..217.212 rows=634 loops=1)
  Output: products.id, products.created_at, products.name
  CTE cte
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=22.50..22.52 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=13.186..13.188 rows=1 loops=1)
          Output: array_agg(("left"((random())::text, 9)))
          ->  Function Scan on pg_catalog.generate_series  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=3.154..10.602 rows=20000 loops=1)
                Output: "left"((random())::text, 9)
                Function Call: generate_series('1'::numeric, '20000'::numeric)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=40.08..78.25 rows=10 width=50) (actual time=26.923..217.113 rows=634 loops=1)
        Output: products.id, products.created_at, products.name
        ->  CTE Scan on cte  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=13.293..13.295 rows=1 loops=1)
              Output: cte.search_for_this
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.products  (cost=40.08..78.13 rows=10 width=50) (actual time=13.622..203.663 rows=634 loops=1)
              Output: products.id, products.created_at, products.name
              Recheck Cond: (products.id = ANY (cte.search_for_this))
              Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 2
              Heap Blocks: exact=541
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on product_id_idx2  (cost=0.00..40.08 rows=10 width=0) (actual time=13.093..13.093 rows=636 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (products.id = ANY (cte.search_for_this))
Planning Time: 0.358 ms
Execution Time: 217.468 ms
```

[`IN`: demo4](https://dbfiddle.uk/LvBjpJ68)

```sql
explain analyze verbose
WITH cte AS MATERIALIZED
  (select unnest(arr) as search_for_this 
   from(select array_agg(r) arr --app would pass the array here
        from (select left(random()::text,9) as r
              from generate_series(1,2e4))_)_)
SELECT "products".* 
FROM "products"
WHERE "id" in (select search_for_this from cte)
LIMIT 37520 OFFSET 0;
```

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=22.80..103.17 rows=10 width=50) (actual time=24.485..47.409 rows=634 loops=1)
  Output: products.id, products.created_at, products.name
  CTE cte
    ->  ProjectSet  (cost=22.50..22.57 rows=10 width=32) (actual time=12.157..14.241 rows=20000 loops=1)
          Output: unnest((array_agg(("left"((random())::text, 9)))))
          ->  Aggregate  (cost=22.50..22.52 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=12.137..12.138 rows=1 loops=1)
                Output: array_agg(("left"((random())::text, 9)))
                ->  Function Scan on pg_catalog.generate_series  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=3.152..10.016 rows=20000 loops=1)
                      Output: "left"((random())::text, 9)
                      Function Call: generate_series('1'::numeric, '20000'::numeric)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.23..80.60 rows=10 width=50) (actual time=24.484..47.333 rows=634 loops=1)
        Output: products.id, products.created_at, products.name
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=0.23..0.33 rows=10 width=32) (actual time=24.343..28.019 rows=19976 loops=1)
              Output: cte.search_for_this
              Group Key: cte.search_for_this
              Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1833kB
              ->  CTE Scan on cte  (cost=0.00..0.20 rows=10 width=32) (actual time=12.161..18.573 rows=20000 loops=1)
                    Output: cte.search_for_this
        ->  Index Scan using product_id_idx2 on public.products  (cost=0.00..8.02 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=19976)
              Output: products.id, products.created_at, products.name
              Index Cond: (products.id = cte.search_for_this)
              Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 0
Planning Time: 0.934 ms
Execution Time: 47.807 ms
```

Comment: As to the *how* and *why*, there's been [quite](https://pganalyze.com/blog/5mins-postgres-performance-in-lists-vs-any-operator-bind-parameters#postgres-index-not-used-with--any-but-is-used-with-in) a [lot](https://pganalyze.com/blog/5mins-postgres-performance-in-vs-any) of [blog](https://kmoppel.github.io/2023-07-04-til-in-is-not-the-same-as-any/) [posts](https://pganalyze.com/blog/5mins-postgres-performance-in-lists-vs-any-operator-bind-parameters) about it.

Comment: Your first example is not suitable because it recomputes the random array for every row in the table and then does the comparison to a different one each time.  This both prevents the use of an index, and contributes to the slowness directly as well.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried the `WHERE "id" IN (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[` solution and the QUERY PLAN has still the `->  Seq Scan on product  (cost=0.00..7.00 rows=200 width=166) (actual time=0.055..0.073 rows=200 loops=1)` in it. Why? Maybe because I have more fields on products table?

Comment: It might also actually be too small to justify reaching for an index. If it really is 200 rows big, that would be my bet

Comment: This would suggest that might be the case: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/n_i5nWiG) - I reduced the above examples to a 40-element array against a 200-row table and it immediately switched to seq scan.